# How to boot from USB flash via EFI?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, grub, uefi

I have setup the following partition table on flash-drive:

```
Disklabel type: gpt
Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048    34815    32768   16M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     34816   854015   819200  400M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3    854016 21825535 20971520   10G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb4  21825536 30214143  8388608    4G Linux filesystem
```

Then I mount `sdb2` as `boot` and `sdb1` as `boot/efi` and do:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=boot/efi --recheck /dev/sdb
grub-mkconfig -o boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Everything went fine according to output of commands.

But when I reboot and select the USB flash-drive from the BIOS boot menu, it says that it fails to boot: with some BIOS message box - I don't even get to console or something.

Almost the same setup on my SSD drive does boot perfectly with EFI - there is `/sys/firmware/efi` folder after boot.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: "some BIOS message box" - What is the message?

Comment: @Ramhound: `Boot failure.` with a title `Warning` and a button `Continue`.

Comment: Did you check the boot config of the device itself? If it failed, chances are the boot manager -- I assume grub2 -- is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

External disks are generally booted through the fallback boot loader filename, which is `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` (for x86-64 systems with 64-bit EFIs). Your installation procedure put the boot loader at `boot/efi`, and probably used a name of `grub.efi` or `grubx64.efi`, although I'm not 100% positive of that. (You should check what it is.) Renaming the files appropriately should fix the problem of getting GRUB to launch, although you may need to re-create the GRUB binary to get it to look for `grub.cfg` in the right place.

A caveat: I'm not intimately familiar with every detail of the `grub-install` command, so I may be missing additional problems.